# How to parse JSON in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table in my database, which contains character varying column and this column has json. I need to write a query, which will somehow parse this json into separate columns.

I found **json_each** function [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) but I can't understand how to work with it.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports native JSON data type since version 9.2.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

I figured it out, guys

if I have a table books
[image]

I can easily write a query

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   data::json->'name' as name
FROM books;
```

And it will result in

[image]

I can also try to get non-existent column

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   data::json->'non_existant' as non_existant
FROM books;
```

And it this case I will get empty result

[image]

Comment: If you're on a recent-enough version of postgres, using `data::jsonb->'foo'` will be slightly more efficient (with 'json' it actually gets re-parsed for every element access).

Comment: @Dmitri In this context it would with `data::jsonb` too. You'd only benefit if you wrapped it in subquery and referenced the casted result from the inner query multiple times in the outer query.

Comment: Use data::json->>'name' if you don't want double quotes around strings. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: `trim('"' FROM (data::json->'name')::text)`  in order to remove quotes

Comment: any solution for the case when one doesn't know structure of the underlying json blob?

Answer (score 65):

Awesome, thanks for sharing. I found that you can go deeper like:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   data::json->'name' as name,
   data::json->'author' ->> 'last_name' as author
FROM books;
```