# Query Json field on postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a json column on my database pgsql
[image]

I need to search keys with localId,
I tried both this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM public.translations
    where datas->>'localId' = 7;
```

[image]
and

```
 SELECT *
    FROM public.translations
        where datas->>'localId'::text = '7';
```

no results.

How can i do it please?

when i make this query i have no values

```
SELECT datas->>'localId' as local
FROM public.translations 
SELECT datas::json->>'localId' as local
FROM public.translations
```

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screenshot is a bit hard to read, but it seems your JSON is in fact a JSON *array*, so you need to pick the first element from there:

```
where (datas -> 0 ->> 'localId')::int = 7
```

or a bit shorter:

```
where (datas #>> '{0,localId}')::int = 7
```

alternatively you can use the contains operator `@>` to check if there is at least one element with `localId = 7`. But the `@>` operator requires `jsonb`, not `json`, so you will need to cast your column

```
where datas::jsonb @> '[{"localId": 7}]'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=510d6376cd0e3548582c26d5fda1e61f)

Comment: Thanks, It's ok when i have only one element in the array but when i have 2 elements and the second element is with value 7 it's not fetched

Comment: @user1428798: the `@>` will do that

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name when i try it i have this error : "ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @> unknown
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.translations  WHERE datas @> '[{"localI...
                                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 48"

Comment: @user1428798: I overlooked that you are using a `json` column rather than the recommended `jsonb`. See my edit, you will have to cast the column

Comment: Thanks very helpful it's ok now !

Comment: and if your sample i want to query value but not exact value select *
from the_table
where datas::jsonb @> '[{"Value": "cc"}]'; and to have the value with "ccc", how can i do it please ? i want to make a like

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `::json` right after `datas` :

```
SELECT *
FROM public.translations
where datas::json->>'localId' = '7';
```

[Related question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626261/how-to-parse-json-in-postgresql)

If you need more informations here is the
[Newest Postgresql Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast both values to the same type

```
where datas->>'localId' = '7'::text;
```

or

```
where (datas->>'localId')::integer = 7;
```

or you should add brackets to you example

```
where (datas->>'localId')::text = '7';
```

Comment: `'7'::text` can be simplified to `'7'` and `(datas->>'localId')::text` can be simplified to `datas->>'localId'`  - the `->>` operator already returns a `text` value

Comment: same i tried (datas->>'localId')::integer = 7; but no results