# how to access one key inside jsonb field?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table like this

```
     Column      │         Type         │                             Modifiers
─────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 id              │ integer              │ not null default
 practice_id     │ character varying(6) │ not null
 date            │ date                 │ not null
 pct_id          │ character varying(3) │
 astro_pu_items  │ double precision     │ not null
 astro_pu_cost   │ double precision     │ not null
 total           │ jsonb                │
```

I need to access total field and find the particular key. So if the key name is sub_total how can I find through query. I'm using Postgres 14.1.

I'm not able to find postgres function which can do that. So guide me here

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626261/how-to-parse-json-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `->` Operator.

```
select total->'sub_total' from tablename;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html