# Postgres 12.9 - Getting the value of a json array on matching key

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a column in my database that stores a json string listing the weapons used in each game activity, what I need to be able to do is return the 'values'->'uniqueWeaponKills'->'basic'->'value' when the 'referenceId' key = 1994645182, and 0 if the key,value pair is not in the column.

Example 'weapons' column data

```json
{
  "weapons": [
    {
      "values": {
        "uniqueWeaponKills": {
          "basic": {
            "value": 14,
            "displayValue": "14"
          }
        },
        "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills": {
          "basic": {
            "value": 0,
            "displayValue": "0"
          }
        },
        "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills": {
          "basic": {
            "value": 0,
            "displayValue": "0%"
          }
        }
      },
      "referenceId": 1994645182
    },
    {
      "values": {
        "uniqueWeaponKills": {
          "basic": {
            "value": 2,
            "displayValue": "2"
          }
        },
        "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills": {
          "basic": {
            "value": 1,
            "displayValue": "1"
          }
        },
        "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills": {
          "basic": {
            "value": 0.5,
            "displayValue": "50%"
          }
        }
      },
      "referenceId": 1853180924
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit 1:
Using the suggestion from Kendle I got to the following query, I haven't seen a way to dynamically look in each of the array elements instead of having to specify the one to look at.
Query

```sql
select weapons::json->'weapons'->1->'values'->'uniqueWeaponKills'->'basic'->>'value' as "uniqueWeaponKills",
weapons::json->'weapons'->1->'referenceId' as "weaponId"
from activities
where (weapons::json->'weapons'->1->>'referenceId')::BIGINT = 1687353095;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT
weapons::json->'values'->> 'uniqueWeaponKills'->>'basic' ->>'value' 
FROM table_name
WHERE 
weapons::json->'referenceId' = 1994645182;
```

See also [How to parse JSON in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626261/how-to-parse-json-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the reference, I was able to get the value by manually specifying the array number to look in, I wasn't able to find anything in the other post or on Postgres documentation for looking through every array item to find the match, but also even specifying the array number threw an error on the WHERE. Added to OP.

Comment: I got the where issue fixed by casting to a bigint before performing the check and that works. Just need a way to dynamically check through each array now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution I am looking for using json_array_elements()

```sql
SELECT obj->'values'->'uniqueWeaponKills'->'basic'->>'value' as "uniqueWeaponKills"
FROM   activities a, json_array_elements(a.weapons#>'{weapons}') obj
WHERE  (obj->>'referenceId')::BIGINT = 1687353095;
```